# When using につれて, does the direction of change have to be the same?

Tags: grammar

I understand that につれて can be used to express changes brought about by A on B where the extent of change in A has a proportional effect on B.

For example, "感染者が増えるにつれて、亡くなる人がどんどん増えていく。"

However, does the direction of this change have to be the same?

For example, can I say something like:

> 雨が降るにつれて、空を飛んでいる鳥が減っていく。

Comment: +1 but it might be worth re-wording a bit. You question currently asks if one thing can increase while the other decreases, but your second example has one thing changing while another thing happens. This is a much broader question than your title suggests.

Comment: Oh I see it now! I meant to convey something like "As the downpour/rain **increases**, the number of birds flying in the sky **decreases**." Not sure what's the best way to say "as the rain increases" though. A quick scan through jisho.org seems like 雨が降り募る is a good option. Do you reckon that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't have to be the same. You can easily use this to describe inverse relationships.

For example you could say things like:

> 晴れの日が増えるにつれて、鬱病患者が減っていく。( As the number of sunny days increases, the number of people with depression decreases)

Here are some more examples:

- 失業率が低下するにつれ，賃金は上昇する傾向がでてきます (Describing the [Phillips curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillips_curve))

  - https://www2.kumagaku.ac.jp/teacher/~sasayama/macroecon/lecture15.html
- 高度が増加するにつれて温度は下がる

  - https://www.google.com/books/edition/%E6%B0%97%E5%80%99%E5%A4%89%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%E6%B0%97%E8%B1%A1%E5%AD%A6/LG4famj6-n0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E9%AB%98%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%8C%E5%A2%97%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E6%B8%A9%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%AF%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B&pg=PA29&printsec=frontcover
- 光は距離が増加するにつれて暗くなっていきます (describing an [inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law))

  - http://jp.littlebits.com/browse-lessons/space-lesson-inverse-square/